# Dynamic discounts for specific products

Tags: class-design, e-commerce

I have a table of discounts/offers, which are only applicable when meeting certain requirements. Example:

- Size: medium, Category: classic, Max. Ingredients: 3, Delivery: collection

Meeting these requirements results in the user having the products for a lower price (absolute price, not relative).

I am thinking about the best way to implement this. Of course I could both check and define these constraints statically in the code, but do you think there could be a dynamic solution? Should each of the offers be represented by a class which implements an Offer interface?

```
Product:
- getPrice()

Offer1 implements Offer:
- getFinalPrice
- checkForConstraints
```

Or am I going at this wrong? Let me know what you think.

Comment: Size: medium, Category: classic, Max. Ingredients: 3, Delivery: collection. Are the conditions of the product or of the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a textbook example of where compositional typing is needed

```
Product:
-getBasePrice()

IOfferConditionsType (interface):
-getOfferConditionsTypeName()
-matchesConditions(?)


//Implement the different offer condition types, you can also implement just one Dynamic conditions type if the conditions are simple and loaded from the DB

Offer:
-getOfferName()
-getOfferDescription()
-IOfferConditionsType // you can store OfferConditionType in the DB to load different types of conditions
-matchesConditions(?)  // call IOfferTypes
-finalPrice(price) //this should be completely separate than matches conditions, you will  need to know the price of an offer without the conditions matching so you can advertise it
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way:

- In production, is it acceptable that the application has to be recompiled and re-deployed whenever a discount definition changes?

If yes, then define all the classes you want. If no, you *must* have the discount definitions read from a file, delivered by a different microservice, editable via a GUI or whatever, but *not* defined in source code.

Comment: If the different offers can't be described with a simple webform or config file, it may be sensible to embed a scripting language that checks the conditions. The offer definitions can then be updated without redeployment, though this opens up potential issues regarding versioning, testing, and security. But if done correctly, this is the most flexible and convenient solution by far.